# Can I program microcontrollers in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, microcontroller

Is it possible somehow to program Arduino or ESP8266 microcontrollers on Kotlin?
Same question about single-board computers (i.e. Raspberry Pi).

Comment: [kotlin-native](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native) only supports a few architectures. AVR- and Cortex M3-based Arduinos aren't supported, and I don't think ESP8266 will ever be since LLVM doesn't even support it. Even if they were, you'll have a hard time running anything bigger than a Hello World program given Kotlin's runtime, memory management, and the tiny amount of memory in an Arduino or a ESP8266. On the other hand, a Raspberry Pi is the same as any other ARM-based Linux computer so there's no issue running Kotlin and the JVM directly.

Comment: Assuming your use of the term single-board computers implies something that it can run an operating system for example linux or windows, then you have the resources on board to do such a thing, yes.  How much work you have to put in, might exceed the work needed to just learn a more natural language for baremetal work.

Comment: This is generally true for a number of non C/ASM languages, even C++ to some extent.  The backend required which is generally handled by the system or various sized libraries on top of the system is more work to port than just using a language that is light on the system (ASM, C, Pascal, etc).  Now some interpreted languages can be compiled (Pascal, Python, JAVA, kotlin, etc) but those languages may have built in system calls, that would then have to be supported by the baremetal backend and/or not supported and fault if encountered.

Comment: @Blender it seems there is something regarding llvm and cortex m3: https://github.com/martinribelotta/cortex-m-llvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Microcontrollers are still computers. if python can be used in Raspberry. then Kotlin can also be used.

First you need compile, JVM(Open source e.g OpenJDK) with that microcontroller toolchain.
Then run the image in the microcontroller. 
Now create a kotlin file, compile it and run it with that JVM.
Thats if the microcontroller runs on a kernel e.g linux

Make sure that microcontroller have enough memory.

Comment: The problem with microcontrollers is they are very resource limited, being able to squeeze a complete enough JVM is the problem, while you will find some big mcus, a large percentage of them will not work.

Comment: Note that while some flavors of Raspberry Pi are in the price range of an MCU eval/breakout board the broadcom chip is in no way a microcontroller.  The board has more than enough resources, and you can if you so desire attempt to port a baremetal complete enough JVM, and then run on top of that.

Comment: In general it is FAR better to use languages that are more suited for the task C/asm being the most common by a very wide margin.

Answer (score 4):

Situation was changed with the new player on the scene named Kotlin/native. Due to the support of LLVM, I think it is possible to compile to native from Kotlin to the desired devices.

Comment: According to https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/1229, Kotlin need 200-300 KB of RAM. I assume that's mostly for its stdlib. In comparison, the ATmega SOCs used by Arduino have 2 or 8 KB of SRAM.

Answer (score 1):

In this moment - no, kotlin use LLVM compiler. Even if microcontroller supports LLVM code, need adaptation for work with "inside components", like interupts, PWM, DAC, ADC, WatchDog and other stuff, and for any mc it adaptations will be unic.

Comment: When i say Kotlin, i mean - Kotlin/Native

Comment: Now - AVR/LLVM team working on arduino support, maybe in future we gets support of LLVM for all arduino compatible boards and MC, and then we can run Kotlin in MC. [https://github.com/avr-llvm](Github repos) .

Answer (score 1):

Yes. LLVM now has (since 8.0) an AVR backend, so you can compile Kotlin/Native source code for Arduino. You can check the development of the [AVR target here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/llvm/lib/Target/AVR).

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Target/AVR/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at llvm.org Port 443

Comment: @Marian Paździoch I fixed the link.